# Computercraft POST request "could not connect"

Tags: post, curl, lua, computercraft

I'm trying to implement OAuth 2.0 into computercraft, and to do so, I have to make the following request:

```
http.post("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code", "client_id={my id here}&scope=email")
```

and I'm just getting a `Could not connect` error

After doing some testing, I found that `http.checkUrl()` works with this url, it works using `curl` in terminal, and `http.get("https://accounts.google.com")` works as well. It seems like the only reason this isn't working is because computercraft isn't handling `POST` requests properly.

What's weird is that `http.get("https://accounts.google.com/o.oauth2/device/code")` doesn't work either, which is really confusing. Although this isn't a valid request, it should succeed with a response of `{"error":"Invalid request"}`, which it does when I use `curl`.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is there some sort of work around?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your configuration you may need to enable the ComputerCraft HTTP API. Or you may need to white-list the *accounts.google.com* domain. You can also disable white-listing altogether if it's enabled.

You can find the settings it in the *config\ComputerCraft.cfg* file.

HTTP posts do work. I am not 100% sure about HTTPS though.

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, I can request `https://accounts.google.com` perfectly fine. It's that specific url that isn't working.

Comment: @tupperkion maybe checkUrl skips the white-listing or something... I have noticed CC doesn't handle error responses too well, does your curl request give a 200?

Comment: @tupperkion CC Wiki is up again: checkUrl does check the whitelist it says. It however does not try to connect, firewall thing? You can do a http.get anywhere else right?

Comment: Yeah, and checkurl says the url I'm trying to request is valid

Answer (score 0):

For debugging setup an [os.PullEvent()](http://computercraft.info/wiki/Os.pullEvent)

Use the [http_failure](http://computercraft.info/wiki/Http_failure_(event)) for sorting

If it still does not work, change the whitelist in your config\ComputerCraft.cfg

```
whitelist = *
```

Or whatever the configuration format is